# Тренажёр(-)кузнечек

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

1. На Новый год мне моя родненькая сестрёнка подарила резинный погостик, или тренажёр-кузнечек!
2. На Новый год мне моя родненькая сестрёнка подарила резинный погостик, или тренажёр кузнечек!

Comment: Первое. Родненький употребляется только в обращениях к кому-то, в качестве нарицательного. Не погостик - а пого стик, pogo stick. Погостик - это маленькое кладбище. Пого — слэм, ассоциирующийся с ранним панк-роком и состоящий в подпрыгиваниях на месте, как правило, с выпрямленной спиной, соединёнными ногами и руками, прижатыми к туловищу. Pogo - название бренда для этого самого приспособления для прыжков. 1921, originally a registered trademark (Germany, 1919), of unknown origin, perhaps formed from elements of the names of the designers.

Comment: Hopping Stilts Are the New French Playthings. ... For France and especially Paris has taken to the "pogo" stick, a stick equipped with two rests for the feet. Inside of the stick is a strong spring so that the "pogoer" may take a series of jumps without straining his powers. The doctors claim that the jarring produced by the successive jumps do not serve to injure the spine, as one might at first suppose. This jumping habit is spreading through France and England and the eastern part of the United States. ["Illustrated World," Sept., 1921]

Comment: Запятая перед или ставится : 2. При наличии уточняющей конструкции перед «или», если ее по смыслу можно заменить на «то есть».

Глеб достал коробку, или ящик, большой и массивный («ящик, большой и массивный» — уточнение).

Я сомневаюсь, что тут нужна запятая. И кузнеч*и*к. 
Неужели, так интересно сочинять фразы с кучей ошибок, а акцент ставить только на одном моменте?

Comment: Леопольд, если раздельно, то я бы написал так: *тренажёр "Кузнечик".*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "кузнеч**и**к" через <kbd>и</kbd> пишется.
2. "тренажёр(?)кузнечик" требует дефис: "тренажёр-кузнечик". Это одно слово, просто в нём 2 основы.

Comment: *Погостик* = *кузнечик*, следовательно запятая.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр если бы не было союза `ИЛИ`, тогда да. А так ОЧП разделяет союз (и он не повторяется много раз) и поэтому запятая не ставится.

Comment: См. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_392#:~:text=%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE.-,%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20%C2%AB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%C2%BB%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%C2%AB%D0%BB%D0%B8%2F%D0%BB%D1%8C,%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE.

Comment: Зонтик, это не ОЧ, а названия одного и того же предмета, то есть последнее поясняет первое, а значит, запятая перед "или" ставится.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец хорошо, убрал третий пункт.

Answer (score -1):

На Новый год мне моя родненькая сестрёнка подарила резинный погостик, или тренажёр-кузнечек!

Мне моя - ошибка.

Кузнечек - ошибка.

Родненькая - неуместно, ошибка. Родненькая, родимый используется только для нарицания при обращениях, со значением "милый, дорогой".

Резинный [Pogo](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pogo) stick или Pogostick - неуместный эпитет, ошибка. Кроме того "резинный" называли натуральный каучук, но впоследствии(и правильнее) стали использовать суффикс ОВА - для обозначения материала, а не природы происхождения НН. Поэтому резинный даже по отношению к элементам тренажёра(в котором даже искусственная резина вряд ли есть, там пластик) - это ваша фантазия. С таким же успехом можно было сказать "подарила мне зефиренный погостик" - но сомневаюсь, что можно оценить грамотность высказывания в этом случае.

погостик - ошибка. [пого-стик](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pogo%20stick) - возможно, допустимо, если транслит, но лучше Пого-стик или даже ПОГО-стик.

погостик, или тренажёр-кузнечек - скорее всего ошибка, потому что Pogostick( тренажёр-кузнечик). Или можно употребить для противопоставления равнозначных слов, но тут одно официальное название, а второе - обиходное.

Но одно не является уточнением другого, так как это не перевод непереводимого Pogo stick. Использование "или" в качестве уточняющего союза не оправдано.*

Скорее всего корректной может быть постановка тирешечки: Pogo stick - или тренажёр-кузнечик.

На Новый год моя родная сестрёнка подарила *резиновый(??)* Pogo stick - или тренажёр-кузнечик!

Тренажёр-кузнечик - неофициальное, народное, название этого устройства. Никаких кавычек "Кузнечик" не нужно.

- фразы похожего вида:

> "Ночь перед рождеством или вечера на хуторе близ диканьки".

> Этанол (или этиловый спирт ) представляет собой спирт с линейной алкильной цепью.

А вот от классика:

> Мнѣ подарили прекрасную собачку (шпица), которая была у меня мѣсяца съ три, и очень меня забавляла. Шишков.

Сравнить с:

> Но есть еще одна верхняя точка на земном шаре, которая называется Северный полюс или Арктика.

> Северный полюс, или Арктика, также имеет холодный климат..

Когда уточнение не является крайним, тогда нужно выделять запятыми, а если это конец фразы, то - скобки, без знака(при определяемом слове), тире(?).

На Новый год моя родная сестрёнка подарила замечательный тренажёр-кузнечик (или Pogo stick)!

А ведь самое-то, снег, Новый год, самое время расчехлить прыгалки. Готовь сани летом, а Пого-стик зимой!